# Ajax Datatable ERROR : No data available in table

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

I tried 2 types of Ajax, one is the append data into datatable way, one is using columns and display array data.

The append data one can work but the result isn't ideal because the datatable is not align well and assoc is not working.

[Ajax append data result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn6DW.png)

So I want to use the "typical" way to display my datatable, but I use the exactly same value and variable which is same with my append data Ajax but I dont know why this Ajax still cant work as the datatable always show "No data available in table" even I can fetch the data. What is the problem?

**Ajax of append data:**(can work)

```
$(document ).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'table_backend2.php',
        mimeType: 'json',
        "processing": true,
        success: function(data2) {
            var aaData=data2['aaData'];
            $.each(aaData, function(i, data) {
                var body = "<tr>";
                body    += "<td>" + data.id+ "</td>";
                body    += "<td>" + data.show_activity_id + "</td>";
                body    += "<td>" + data.nasa_id + "</td>";
                body    += "<td>" + data.game_show_id + "</td>";
                body    += "<td>" + data.account_id + "</td>";
                body    += "</tr>";
                $( "#showTable" ).append(body);
            });
            $( "#showTable" ).DataTable();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Fail!');
        }
    });
});
```

**Typical datatable Ajax** (Always show no data available0

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        'type': 'GET',
        'url':'table_backend2.php'
    }).done(function(data) {
        var aaData=data['aaData'];
        $("#showTable").DataTable({
            "aaData":aaData,
            "columns": [
                { aaData: "id"},
                { aaData: "show_activity_id" },
                { aaData: "nasa_id" },
                { aaData: "game_show_id" },
                { aaData: "account_id"},
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

**php file**
(I just put the fetch records part as I worry the code will be too big)

```
     ## Fetch records
      $empQuery = "SELECT * from analysis_data.show_incentive";
      $empRecords = mysqli_query($connData['conn'], $empQuery);
      $data = array();
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
         $data[] = array( 
            "id"=>$row['id'],
            "show_activity_id"=>$row['show_activity_id'],
            "nasa_id"=>$row['nasa_id'],
            "game_show_id"=>$row['game_show_id'],
            "account_id"=>$row['account_id']
         );
      }

      ## Response
      $response = array(
         "draw" => intval($draw),
         "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
         "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
         "aaData" => $data
      );

      echo json_encode($response);
   }
```